# how to prevent triggering of job by Webhook

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, monorepo, bitbucket-webhook

I have git monorepo repository with multiple projects inside. So I have following structure of Jenkinsfiles in this repo:

```
|-Jenkinsfile (root one)
|-projectA
| |-Jenkinsfile (for projectA)
| |- ... (project files)
|-projectB
  |-Jenkinsfile (for projectB)
  |- ... (project files)
```

In main root Jenkinsfile I have logic to check PR changed files and then trigger projects pipelines when files in specific project were changed.

And I have Webhook.

My problem is that all those 3 pipelines are triggered by Webhook. So my current state is:

1. I change something in projectA and create PR
2. Webhook triggers all pipeliens: root, projectA and projectB
3. root pipeline notices that changes were made on projectA and triggers projectA pipeline

So in runs I have:

- one run of root pipeline triggered by webhook
- one run of projectA pipeline triggered by webhook
- one run of projectB pipeline triggered by webhook
- one run of projectA pipeline triggered by upstream

And I want to have:

- one run of root pipeline triggered by webhook
- one run of projectA pipeline triggered by upstream

I cannot change webhook nature because it's monorepo so its sent every time anyone does anything in any project. So I need to prevent projectA and projectB pipelines from reacting on incoming webhook.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
multibranchPipelineJob(...) {
            branchSources {
                branchSource {
                    source {
                        ...
                    }
                    strategy {
                        allBranchesSame {
                            props {
                                suppressAutomaticTriggering()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
        }
```

This setting prevents webhook triggers to start job.